# laravel - @yield('content') broken

Tags: php, css, html, laravel-5

today i just try to test my codes and i got a weird problrm.
i have a app blade to use as my yied or shared header and footer
the codes is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <title>Diva - Beauty salon template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Page Preloder -->
    <div id="preloder" style="display: none;">
        <div class="loader" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Header section -->
    <header class="header-section" dir="rtl">
        <div class="header-warp">
            <!-- logo -->
            <a href="home.html" class="site-logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <!-- responsive -->
            <div class="nav-switch">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <!-- Navigation Menu -->
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li class="active"><a href="/home">{{ __('general.Anohe') }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">{{ __('general.about-us')}}</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">{{ __('general.sell-place') }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">{{ __('general.about') }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/contact-us">{{ __('general.contact-with-us') }}</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="header-right mb-4">
                <a href="" class="site-btn sb-line sb-big">09359127500</a>
                <a href="/home" class="site-btn sb-big">{{ __('general.menu') }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Header section end -->

  <div class="container">
      @include('...shared.message')
      <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
            @yield('content')
      </div>
  </div>


    <!-- Footer section end -->
  <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container bottom_border">
            <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-sm-4 col-md col-sm-4  col-12 col">
            <h5 class="headin5_amrc col_white_amrc pt2">Find us</h5>
            <!--headin5_amrc-->
            <p class="mb10">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> 9878/25 sec 9 rohini 35 </p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>  +91-9999878398  </p>
            <p><i class="fa fa fa-envelope"></i> info@example.com  </p>


            </div>


            <div class=" col-sm-4 col-md  col-6 col">
            <h5 class="headin5_amrc col_white_amrc pt2">Quick links</h5>
            <!--headin5_amrc-->
            <ul class="footer_ul_amrc">
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Image Rectoucing</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Clipping Path</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Hollow Man Montage</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Ebay & Amazon</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Hair Masking/Clipping</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Image Cropping</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!--footer_ul_amrc ends here-->
            </div>


            <div class=" col-sm-4 col-md  col-6 col">
            <h5 class="headin5_amrc col_white_amrc pt2">Quick links</h5>
            <!--headin5_amrc-->
            <ul class="footer_ul_amrc">
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Remove Background</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Shadows & Mirror Reflection</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Logo Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Vectorization</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Hair Masking/Clipping</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Image Cropping</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!--footer_ul_amrc ends here-->
            </div>


            <div class=" col-sm-4 col-md  col-12 col">
            <h5 class="headin5_amrc col_white_amrc pt2">Follow us</h5>
            <!--headin5_amrc ends here-->

            <ul class="footer_ul2_amrc">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fleft padding-right"></i> </a><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...<a href="#">https://www.lipsum.com/</a></p></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fleft padding-right"></i> </a><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...<a href="#">https://www.lipsum.com/</a></p></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter fleft padding-right"></i> </a><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...<a href="#">https://www.lipsum.com/</a></p></li>
            </ul>
            <!--footer_ul2_amrc ends here-->
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>


            <div class="container">
            <ul class="foote_bottom_ul_amrc">
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!--foote_bottom_ul_amrc ends here-->
            <p class="text-center">Copyright @2017 | Designed With by <a href="#">Your Company Name</a></p>

            <ul class="social_footer_ul">
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://kalarikendramdelhi.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <!--social_footer_ul ends here-->
        </div>

    </footer>

  <!-- Footer -->

    <!--====== Javascripts & Jquery ======-->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script><div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>


</body></html>
```

and two other page with section
page one

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div dir="rtl" >
    <div class="d-flex d-inline-flex" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
        <div class="shadow-sm border d-block h-100" style="width: 20%; ">
            <p>
منو
            </p>
            <div class="w-100 mb-2"><a href="" style=" color: #000000">پوشاک</a><p class="fa fa-angle-left float-left ml-2"></p></div>
            <div class="w-100 mb-2"><a href="" style=" color: #000000">الکترونیکی</a><p class="fa fa-angle-left float-left ml-2"></p></div>
            <div class="w-100 mb-2"><a href="" style=" color: #000000">کتای</a><p class="fa fa-angle-left float-left ml-2"></p></div>
            <div class="w-100 mb-2"><a href="" style=" color: #000000">بازی و سرگرمی</a><p class="fa fa-angle-left float-left ml-2"></p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="shadow border mr-3 h-100" style="width: 80%;">
            <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ul>

              <!-- The slideshow -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img style="height: 300px;width: 100%" src="http://smarterware.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/technology1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img style="height: 300px;width: 100%" src="https://www.cmo.com/content/dam/CMO/Home%20Page/1046x616_Modern-Commerce-2.0-Technology-Sets-The-Stage-For-A-New-Round-Of-Disruption.jpg" alt="Chicago">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img style="height: 300px;width: 100%" src="https://sohopress.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/web-summit-feature_1200x675_hero_110717.jpg" alt="New York">
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Left and right controls -->
              <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
              </a>
              <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
              </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow border mt-3">
        <p>
    ایران نت
        </p>
        <hr style="border-color: #bdbdbd;">
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex d-inline-flex" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="shadow border mt-3" style="width: 20%">
            <p>
آخرین اخبار
            </p>
            <hr style="border-color: #ff8a05">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 60px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word;"><a href="/news">  شاسی بلند لامبورگینی اوروس با تیونینگ TopCar معرفی شد     </a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 60px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word;"><a href="/news1">  اینتل دانگل هوش مصنوعی جدید خود را معرفی کرد    </a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 60px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word;"><a href="/news2"> چهارمین همایش آینده وب و موبایل    </a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item" style="height: 60px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word;"><a href="/news3">  بزرگ‌ترین کارخانه تولید داروهای ضدسرطان خاورمیانه در ایران افتتاح شد    </a></li>
              <li class="list-group-item"  style="height: 60px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word;"><a href="/news4"> جگوار لندرور در صنعت موتورسیکلت سرمایه‌گذاری می‌کند    </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="shadow border mt-3 mr-3" style="width: 80%; height: 350px">
            <img class="w-100 h-100" src="https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2018/06/fortnite.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=782"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow border mt-3">
        <p>
جدید ترین ها
        </p>
        <hr style="border-color: #bdbdbd;">
        <div class=" d-inline-flex" style="height: 300px">
        @foreach($products as $product)
            <div class="w-25 m-2">
              <div class="h-50 p-2">
                  <img class="w-75 h-100" style="border-radius: 20px;" src="/image/products/{{$product->id}}product1.jpg"/>
              </div>
              <div class="p-2" style=" overflow: hidden;   word-wrap: normal; height: 35%;">
                  <a href="">{{$product->pname}}</a>
                  <p>{{$product->description}} </p>
              </div>
              <a href="" class="text-secondary font-weight-light">توضیحات محصول</a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow border mt-3">
        <p>
دیجیکالا
        </p>
        <hr style="border-color: #bdbdbd;">
        <div class=" d-inline-flex">
        @if(isset($Dproducts))
            @foreach($Dproducts as $product)
                <div class="w-25 border m-2">
                  <div class="h-50 p-2 border">
                      <img class="w-100 h-100" src="/image/products/{{$product->id}}product1.jpg"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="h-25 p-2 border">
                      <a href="">{{$product->pname}}</a>
                      <p style=" overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word;">{{$product->description}} </p>
                  </div>
                  <a href="" class="text-secondary font-weight-light">توضیحات محصول</a>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

and page two

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')


<div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center">Contac Form</h2>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 pb-5">

            <div class="container">
            <h1>Contact US Form</h1>

            @if(Session::has('success'))
               <div class="alert alert-success">
                 {{ Session::get('success') }}
               </div>
            @endif
            <form method="post" action="{{route('contactus.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" value="{{old('name')}}">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control" value="{{old('email')}}">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('message') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter Message" class="form-control" value="{{old('message')}}"></textarea>
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('message') }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Contact US!</button>
            </div>

            </form>

            </div>
                    <!--Form with header-->


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@include('...shared.errors')

@endsection
```

problem is my shared blade work in my first page without problem.but in my second page CSS file don't work .
i test it a lot my self and i find out that when my address bar get more than one / this problem happening . 
route of my first page is /home and my second page is /page/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with `@yield`, the problem is you’re using a *relative* path for your CSS files, so if your page is within a folder the URL will become invalid.

Instead, use the `url()` helper in Laravel to automatically prepend the application’s base URL to your CSS URLs:

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/bts.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/style.css') }}">
```

Comment: @AhmadVahedi No problem. Glad to help.